# kafka CommitFailedException: The coordinator is not aware of this member. Though poll on every 100 millis and single consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka 1.1.0, single consumer and I get this error though my poll is very quick, one poll on every 100 milli seconds elapsed. I use manual commit and duration between two commit request may change (can be even hours). But not poll.

I still get this error "The coordinator is not aware of this member." with message

> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot
> be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the
> partitions to another member. This means that the time between
> subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured
> max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is
> spending too much time message processing. You can address this either
> by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of
> batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

What could be the reason for this error. I have searched all over the place but I couldn't get any information in my context of problem.

Both "max.poll.interval.ms" and session timeout are default.

From logs I can see last successful commit was at "11:20:11.677" and failed commit was at "11:20:35.742" just 24 seconds apart.

Its application process with its own group id. I can confirm there was no other process running with same group id.

This is from debug log:

> 2018-11-17 17:03:39.227 - DEBUG o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator
> Attempt to heartbeat failed for since member id
> consumer-1-e237c8ed-fed7-4687-be4d-99e333e48af3 is not valid.
>
> 2018-11-17 17:03:39.227 - DEBUG o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator
> Disabling heartbeat thread 2018-11-17 17:08:09.241 - DEBUG
> o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Sending metadata request
> (type=MetadataRequest, topics=) to node 10.0.10.220:9092 (id: 1 rack:
> null)
>
> 2018-11-17 17:08:09.241 - DEBUG
> org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version
> 505 to Cluster(id = 5zFDtyruTP-cIctUkxG0Pg, nodes = [10.0.10.222:9092
> (id: 3 rack: null), 10.0.10.220:9092 (id: 1 rack: null),
> 10.0.10.221:9092 (id: 2 rack: null)], partitions = [])
>
> 2018-11-17 17:12:09.472 - DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Node 3
> disconnected.
>
> 2018-11-17 17:12:09.472 - DEBUG
> o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Sending metadata request
> (type=MetadataRequest, topics=) to node 10.0.10.220:9092 (id: 1 rack:
> null)
>
> 2018-11-17 17:12:09.472 - DEBUG
> org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version
> 506 to Cluster(id = 5zFDtyruTP-cIctUkxG0Pg, nodes = [10.0.10.222:9092
> (id: 3 rack: null), 10.0.10.221:9092 (id: 2 rack: null),
> 10.0.10.220:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], partitions = [])
>
> 2018-11-17 17:17:09.502 - DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Initialize
> connection to node 10.0.10.222:9092 (id: 3 rack: null) for sending
> metadata request
>
> 2018-11-17 17:17:09.503 - DEBUG
> o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient Initiating connection to node
> 10.0.10.221:9092 (id: 2 rack: null)
>
> 2018-11-17 17:17:09.503 - DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Sending metadata request
> (type=MetadataRequest, topics=) to node 10.0.10.220:9092 (id: 1 rack:
> null)
>
> 2018-11-17 17:17:09.503 - DEBUG
> o.a.kafka.common.network.Selector  Created socket with SO_RCVBUF =
> 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node 2
>
> 2018-11-17
> 17:17:09.503 - DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Completed
> connection to node 2. Fetching API versions.
>
> 2018-11-17 17:17:09.503 -
> DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Initiating API versions
> fetch from node 2.
>
> 2018-11-17 17:17:09.503 - DEBUG
> org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version
> 507 to Cluster(id = 5zFDtyruTP-cIctUkxG0Pg, nodes = [10.0.10.220:9092
> (id: 1 rack: null), 10.0.10.221:9092 (id: 2 rack: null),
> 10.0.10.222:9092 (id: 3 rack: null)], partitions = [])
>
> 2018-11-17 17:17:09.503 - DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Recorded
> API versions for node 3: (Produce(0): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], Fetch(1): 0
> to 7 [usable: 7], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Metadata(3): 0
> to 5 [usable: 5], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], StopReplica(5):
> 0 [usable: 0], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 4 [usable: 4],
> ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 3
> [usable: 3], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], FindCoordinator(10):
> 0 to 1 [usable: 1], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Heartbeat(12):
> 0 to 1 [usable: 1], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SyncGroup(14):
> 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 1 [usable: 1],
> ListGroups(16): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable:
> 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 2
> [usable: 2], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DeleteRecords(21):
> 0 [usable: 0], InitProducerId(22): 0 [usable: 0],
> OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 [usable: 0], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0
> [usable: 0], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 [usable: 0], EndTxn(26): 0
> [usable: 0], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 [usable: 0], TxnOffsetCommit(28):
> 0 [usable: 0], DescribeAcls(29): 0 [usable: 0], CreateAcls(30): 0
> [usable: 0], DeleteAcls(31): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 to
> 1 [usable: 1], AlterConfigs(33): 0 [usable: 0],
> AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0
> [usable: 0], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 [usable: 0],
> CreatePartitions(37): 0 [usable: 0], CreateDelegationToken(38): 0
> [usable: 0], RenewDelegationToken(39): 0 [usable: 0],
> ExpireDelegationToken(40): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeDelegationToken(41):
> 0 [usable: 0], DeleteGroups(42): 0 [usable: 0])
>
> 2018-11-17
> 17:17:09.503 - DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Completed
> connection to node 2. Fetching API versions.
>
> 2018-11-17 17:17:09.503 -
> DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Initiating API versions
> fetch from node 2.
>
> 2018-11-17 17:17:09.503 - DEBUG
> org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version
> 507 to Cluster(id = 5zFDtyruTP-cIctUkxG0Pg, nodes = [10.0.10.220:9092
> (id: 1 rack: null), 10.0.10.221:9092 (id: 2 rack: null),
> 10.0.10.222:9092 (id: 3 rack: null)], partitions = [])
>
> 2018-11-17 17:17:09.503 - DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Recorded
> API versions for node 3: (Produce(0): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], Fetch(1): 0
> to 7 [usable: 7], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Metadata(3): 0
> to 5 [usable: 5], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], StopReplica(5):
> 0 [usable: 0], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 4 [usable: 4],
> ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 3
> [usable: 3], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], FindCoordinator(10):
> 0 to 1 [usable: 1], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Heartbeat(12):
> 0 to 1 [usable: 1], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SyncGroup(14):
> 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 1 [usable: 1],
> ListGroups(16): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable:
> 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 2
> [usable: 2], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DeleteRecords(21):
> 0 [usable: 0], InitProducerId(22): 0 [usable: 0],
> OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 [usable: 0], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0
> [usable: 0], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 [usable: 0], EndTxn(26): 0
> [usable: 0], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 [usable: 0], TxnOffsetCommit(28):
> 0 [usable: 0], DescribeAcls(29): 0 [usable: 0], CreateAcls(30): 0
> [usable: 0], DeleteAcls(31): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 to
> 1 [usable: 1], AlterConfigs(33): 0 [usable: 0],
> AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0
> [usable: 0], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 [usable: 0],
> CreatePartitions(37): 0 [usable: 0], CreateDelegationToken(38): 0
> [usable: 0], RenewDelegationToken(39): 0 [usable: 0],
> ExpireDelegationToken(40): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeDelegationToken(41):
> 0 [usable: 0], DeleteGroups(42): 0 [usable: 0]) 2018-11-17
> 17:17:09.503 - DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  Recorded
> API versions for node 2: (Produce(0): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], Fetch(1): 0
> to 7 [usable: 7], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Metadata(3): 0
> to 5 [usable: 5], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], StopReplica(5):
> 0 [usable: 0], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 4 [usable: 4],
> ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 3
> [usable: 3], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], FindCoordinator(10):
> 0 to 1 [usable: 1], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Heartbeat(12):
> 0 to 1 [usable: 1], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SyncGroup(14):
> 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 1 [usable: 1],
> ListGroups(16): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable:
> 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 2
> [usable: 2], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DeleteRecords(21):
> 0 [usable: 0], InitProducerId(22): 0 [usable: 0],
> OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 [usable: 0], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0
> [usable: 0], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 [usable: 0], EndTxn(26): 0
> [usable: 0], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 [usable: 0], TxnOffsetCommit(28):
> 0 [usable: 0], DescribeAcls(29): 0 [usable: 0], CreateAcls(30): 0
> [usable: 0], DeleteAcls(31): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 to
> 1 [usable: 1], AlterConfigs(33): 0 [usable: 0],
> AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0
> [usable: 0], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 [usable: 0],
> CreatePartitions(37): 0 [usable: 0], CreateDelegationToken(38): 0
> [usable: 0], RenewDelegationToken(39): 0 [usable: 0],
> ExpireDelegationToken(40): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeDelegationToken(41):
> 0 [usable: 0], DeleteGroups(42): 0 [usable: 0])

I see member id not unique message in debug and kafka consumer client keeps retrying for connection.

Comment: Did you use the standalone consumer with a `group.id` happened to be the same with some other consumer group?

Comment: @amethystic nope. Its application process with its own group id. I can confirm there was no other process running with same group id.

Comment: @amethystic I have updated with debug log of kafka client. Please see if that helps. I am not understanding as to why this happened.